# Unity, Using Statement and PerRequestLifetimeManager

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

I'm using Unity in my project. But I'm unsure whether I should be using the `using` statement or not as I'm using the `PerRequestLifetimeManager`.

Simple example:

Injection:

```
container.RegisterType<IDataContext, MyContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

Usage:

```
class MyClass
{
     private readonly IDataContext _context;

     public MyClass(IDataContext context)
     {
           _context = context;
     }

     public string MyMethod()
     {
          // 1. Is this needed?
          using (var u = _context)
          {
               var customers = u.Set<Customer>().OrderBy(o => o.Name);
               // ........
          }

          // 2. OR can I just do this
          var customers = _context.Set<Customer>().OrderBy(o => o.Name);
```

As I'm using `PerRequestLifetimeManager()` in my injection, does this negate the requirement of the `using` statement as the context will be disposed after every http request anyway?

Comment: This is actually an unfair question. Because, from the tags, I suspect that `MyClass` implements `IDisposable`. In which case, you should dispose on `MyClass.Dispose`. However, your IOC container should dispose on the end of its scoped lifetime...

Comment: I don't understand how it's "unfair"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice to use Unit of Work and Repository patterns while you are working with MVC4. While you are creating every time of our context best to register your context in the UnityConfig.cs file located at App_Start folder. as

```
container.RegisterType<IDataContext, MyContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

after this when you start your application the context will be in open till your application closed. so, do not use the `using` statement at the use of context. It will dispose your context after complete of `using` and the context will not available further and when use context after closing `using` then you must got an exception like **context is not available**. so, just use

```
var customers = _context.Set<Customer>().OrderBy(o => o.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i thought.

Answer (score 2):

If you would use using then you would immediately dispose DbContext and if you try to access it again it will result in exception, so 1 approach is generally bad idea. 2 would work but what if there would occur problem in DbContext, for instance new data that you would like to persist will be not compliant to db design (for instance indexes). In such case you will be unable to recreate DbContext. My advice would be to register and then resolve factory method for DbContexts:

```
class MyClass
{
     private readonly Func<IDataContext> _contextFactory;

     public MyClass(Func<IDataContext> contextFactory)
     {
           _contextFactory = contextFactory;
     }

     public string MyMethod()
     {
           // 1. Is this needed?
           using (var u = _contextFactory())
           { 
               var customers = u.Set<Customer>().OrderBy(o => o.Name);
               // ........
           }
     }
```